# How to create a Dynamic page using MySQL Primary key?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am using WordPress and I have a large database of movies which is currently displayed in a tabular form. I want to show the individual movie data with more details on a page but I don't want to create separate page for each movie.

If the user clicks on a movie title, s/he should be directed to a page which displays all the information pulled from the MySQL database linked to the movie. It should be something like a search result displayed in a page structure. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

With php. You're not going to be able to hook it up directly to the database, you have to wrap the MySQL code in php to get the desired functionality.

[This blog posting may help clarify](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/getting-started-with-wordpress-development/).

Comment: Thanks. Will look into it.